# Changing character (time) to numeric in r

Tags: r, time, character

My data set contains a character column showing time as "12:00:00 PM". Could you please let me know if there is any way to show this as 1200 (numeric) value?

I have tried the following code but it give me a large int number:

```
 time = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%H:%M:%S %p"))
```

Comment: `as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct("12:00:00 PM", format = "%H:%M:%S %p"), "%H%M"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use string functions to get the first four digits:

```r
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
"12:00:00 PM" %>%
  str_split_fixed(":", 3) %>%
  extract(1:2) %>%
  str_c(collapse = "") %>%
  as.numeric()
#> [1] 1200
```